# Show/Hide Rows Per Dropdown Selection

Tags: vba, excel, show-hide

I found code online as an example that I have tweaked to show or hide specific rows depending on the selection I choose within a dropdown in my Excel file.

The macro is not working no matter what I try.

My code is as follows (also attached screenshot of rows under question 2 (2a - 2d) that are not showing/hiding)  [image: Screenshot of Excel Doc]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$F$13" Then
If Range("F13").Value = "Yes" Then
Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("F13").Value = "No" Then
Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("F13").Value = " " Then
Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Right now, your code should work if A) This code is in the worksheet you want it to run on (right click the sheet tab and go to "View Code", this code should be there), B) The cell that's changing is F13.   What is your F13, a data validation?  You expect the row to be hidden if F13 is "No" or a [space], correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `End If` missing. I assume the value of the target cell (F13) needs to be tested for it's value. If the value is "Yes", it should unhide row 14:17, if it is " " (spacebar) it should hide them and if it is "No" is should hide them as well. Other values will not affect the hiding/unhiding of the rows.
There should be a second `End If` before `End Sub`, so that all the if-statements above are wrapped within the Address check.

Also note that this code should be placed in the worksheet itself, since you want to hook into the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Try this in a worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$F$13" Then 'Check if the changed value is indeed in F13

    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Show the rows if the value is Yes
    ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Hide them when it's No
    ElseIf Target.Value = " " Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Or space
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

Other remarks:

- Instead of `ActiveSheet` you can also use `Me` (`Me.Rows...`) In this scenario they probably do the same. However, if you change the value on a worksheet from another worksheet (e.g. formula that recalculates), `Me` will reference the changed worksheet that fires the event, whereas activeworksheet will affect the currently active sheet.
- Use Target instead of referencing the Range again. Target is a range object that is already in memory. Hence execution will be faster compared to accessing the worksheet again.

Comment: Thank you so much, this truly helped and the code is now workign correctly within the worksheet! I moved the code from the workbook to Sheet1 (clearly shows you how much of a bigger I am ;) and have added in all of the suggested edits along with the additional missing "End If" line. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of properly intending your code helping you identify an issue.  You're missing an End IF statement.  Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$F$13" Then
    If Range("F13").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    If Range("F13").Value = "No" Then
      Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If Range("F13").Value = " " Then
        Rows("14:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

You may also want to use:

```
If Range("F13").Value = ""
```

instead of

```
If Range("F13").Value = " "
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this got me back on track & helped me get the code working! :)